# Correct way to update frontend when backend changes

Tags: node.js, postgresql, reactjs, express, knex.js

I'm currently setting up the following application:

- Node backend with Express
- Postgres DB with Knex as an interface
- React frontend

Everything is working as intended and I am making good progress, my question is more architectural:

**What is the preferred/recommended/best way to notify the frontend when database changes occur?**

I saw that Postgres has a `LISTEN/NOTIFY` feature but that is not currently (ever) supported by Knex (https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/285).

My thoughts:

- Polling (every x seconds query the DB). This seems wasteful and antiquated but it would be easy to set up.
- Sockets. Rewrite all my Express endpoints to use sockets?
- ?

I'm interested to see how others handle this.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you have to rewrite all of your endpoints to use sockets?

Comment: If you want to notify your client application about updates your best bet is to use websockets. But i can hardly imagine a use case, where you want every client to be notified on every database update. Give us some insights into the nature of the application you are trying to develop.

Comment: @trixn: It's a feed of items that can be locked/pending/accepted/etc so every client does need to be notified of changes.

Comment: @adrice727: because currently the endpoints return json which the frontend ingests and handles. Using sockets would require a rewrite of both I think

Comment: You can still use your endpoints for receiving e.g. initial data. Websockets are the common way to send updates to the client, maybe server-sent events could be an alternative. About listen/notify i can't really tell anything but i can't see why you would need this. You could just trigger the update in the moment you alter the database because that must happen somewhere in your code.

Comment: Agreed. LISTEN/NOTIFY is more useful when there are multiple DB clients (apps) which might be independently updating things. If your app is the only client of your DB, just handle it all in your code.

Comment: @trixn good idea yeah, the initial requests take place as they are now but sockets emit events on DB changes and any clients connected will receive updates. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul good to know, thanks!

Comment: You can use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) to implement proper `LISTEN` handler. See [the example](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#listen--notify).

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar situation before. I have a front end which connects via web sockets to the API. The API emits a message on successful database commit with the API endpoint matching the update. The front end components listen for these update socket messages and if the updated type is relevant to that component the component will query the API endpoint over https for the new data. Using a web socket only to advertise that an update is available won't necessitate rewriting the entire API.